# подключение Qiwi интерфейса v1.1 для поставщика услуг

Tags: php, https, qiwi

Доброго времени, с недавнего времени Qiwi отключила свою платежку для интернет магазинов (тех кто успел подключиться не тронули все работает) отправил интерфейс на доработку, в замен предложив упрощенную систему документация интерфейса тут -> http://qiwi.kz/static/data/how-to-become-provider/interface_podkl_usl.pdf я в отправки таких вещей не силен, старую систему подключал но вот с новой пока не могу разобраться, прошу помощи по этому. Для начала решил протестировать отправку запроса на проверку оплаты - реализовывать решил на php (тут может я ошибаюсь и нужно по другому на jquery например поправьте если не прав) делаю так вроде все по документации:

```
$payparams = array(
'command' => 'check',
'txn_id'  => '1234567',
'account' => '4957835959',
'sum' => '200.00'
 );

$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://service.someprv.ru:8443/payment_app.cgi',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array($payparams))
));
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

echo "Ответ: ".$response;
```

Но вот почему то ответ не приходит, так же для теста пробовал использовать их тестовый сервис -> http://www.qiwi.kz/ru/provider-test/ но тоже все одно - ошибка, так как видимо интерфейс запустили недавно в интернете кроме документации киви каких то примеров я не нашел, может кто уже делал такое? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: `https://service.someprv.ru:8443/payment_app.cgi` - фиктивная ссылка, для примера. Скорей всего, Вам необходимо получить у Киви ссылку на их API.

Comment: @Konstantin Mitjurin да) дошло) я в принципе разобрался уже почти до конца как последние нюансы настрою - постараюсь выложить тут подробную реализацию, а то в гугле нет чего то на подобии так как систему они новую запустили - может кому пригодится еще